# Sort Array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a script which gets some values from a DB.

The structure of the vars is as the following:

```
$dump["likes"] = 1234;
$likes["data"][$i]["name"] = "ABCDEFG";

for($i=0;$i<=$max;$i++){
    $data[$i]["likes"] = $dump["likes"];
    $data[$i]["name"] = $likes["data"][$i]["name"];

}

//Print sorted array here (highest value in "like" first)
```

I just need a way to find out in which entry the biggest "likes" are :)

So far i have tried array_multisort, but it showed me "inconsistent size" or some error...

Thanks for all your help!

EDIT:

When i print($data) outside of the end loop it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [likes] => 3485109 [name] => Google ) [1] => Array ( [likes] => 78535 [name] => Youtube ) [2] => Array ( [likes] => 2433041 [name] => Bing ))
```

I would like to have an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [likes] => 3485109 [name] => Google ) [1] => Array ( [likes] => 2433041 [name] => Bing ) [2] => Array ( [likes] => 78535 [name] => Youtube ))

//Sorted by "likes"
```

Comment: Please always quote the exact error message so people can help you.

Comment: I'd recommend to do the sorting in your DB query using "ORDER BY" it's much simpler, cleaner and probably faster!

Comment: it's not possible, because the $dump["likes"] isn't actually in the DB but pulled from an external site... Please check the EDIT for more info about the array structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
function cmp($a, $b){
  if ($a['likes']>$b['likes'])
     return 1;
  else if ($a['likes']<$b['likes'])
    return -1;
  else return 0;
}
usort($data, 'cmp');
```

Comment: One word, GREAT :) Thanks Ivan for your help!